# MySQL Syntax With Simple Joins

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm having trouble figuring out why this query does not work. Names have been sanitized as this is proprietary code.

```
QRY: 
SELECT l.albert, o.ben, m.caleb, m.dennis, m.edgar
    FROM octopus o, lorax l, monkey m
WHERE o.ben = l.ben
    AND l.franklin= m.franklin
    AND o.ben= :ben
ORDER BY l.albert DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'QRY: SELECT l.albert, o.ben, m.caleb, m.dennis, m' at line 1
```

Comment: So have you checked the manual?

Comment: I have, or I wouldn't have posted. It seems like a silly question because I'm pretty sure I'm missing something fairly obvious.

Comment: I don't see `SELECT l.albert, o.OrderNo, m.ben` .. are you sure this is the query that is throwing the error?

Comment: The query seems fine. The sanitization has probably hidden the cause of the error. Some keywords are reserved. Check that.

Comment: @Shredder: Fixed... I sanitized it manually, but I double-checked it and that should be the correct error message now.

Comment: The only problem I see is the `QRY: `, has that been appended into the start of the query string?

Comment: Good to have a second pair of eyes... that was rather silly of me.

Comment: Again a case where the error message tells a person exactly what they need to know. Don't understand why people seem to be unwilling to accept that oftentimes error messages mean exactly what they say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you have

```
"QRY: "
```

at the beginning of your query. It should start with

```
"SELECT ...
```